# Form submit going to the wrong route

Tags: laravel, forms, controller

I am saving data from a simple form in my Laravel project.

While submitting, it should go to the `route` that is predefined for `store()` method. I use such code:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

It goes to the route that is for `index()` method. Any help?

In `store()` method, I have such code:

```
$posts = new Post;

$posts->title = $request->input('title');
$posts->body = $request->input('body');
$posts->save();

return redirect('/');
```

My `web.php` contains:

```
Route::resource('/','PostsController');
```

Comment: Please post your routes file.

Comment: I will add it to my post

Comment: Can you also show us the rest of the form please.

Comment: First of all, don't use laravelcollective's form. This is an old style. You can do everything without it.

Comment: @SandOfVega I do not know that much in Laravel. I am watching the videos where he uses this form. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct bro.. The only reason you're going to index is because of the 
return redirect('/'); in the store function... Check whether youdata is saved in the database or not...

Comment: It is not saved. Even if I don't write any redirect statement it goes to my index.

Comment: If I rename this post-method route, for example, Route::post('/store'), it works. The problem seems to be in my form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested to see if this actually saves the data still? With Route resources, the route will be the same for both `store` and `index` methods, just a different HTTP method.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer but the 2nd sentence is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is working well & data saved in the database. You return `redirect('/')` it to your `index()` method, so you don't understand the difference. Check your database.